# sudo add-apt-repository throws an exception

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm running ubuntu 14.10 on VMware player at my office.

Whenever I try to add a repository, I get this exception.

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1174, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1090, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1086, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 924, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1221, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 836, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 509, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 500, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I picked smplayer just to test app-get.  I was able to set up the browser so I can connect to the internet and ping something like yahoo.com, but I don't know if there are other network settings I'm missing.

Comment: Next time you post terminal output, please format it as **code** (`{}`-button) instead of as blockquote (`"`-button). The reason is that blockquote-formatted paragraphs ignore line breaks and have no fixed but dynamic width font, wile code formatting has those features. Thank you! :)

Comment: Well, _I_ already edited it for you... ;-)

Comment: Do you access the internet through a proxy server?

Comment: Yes.  It is a proxy server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define proxy environment variable and tell sudo to use it (with -E flag):

```
export http_proxy=http://<proxy>:<port>
export https_proxy=http://<proxy>:<port>
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
```

If you have to use username and password for proxy, use this syntax:

```
export https_proxy=<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I was ultimately able to go on and install the package I was after.  Appreciate the help.